# After upgrading to 1.16 I get a warning about "experimental settings"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After I upgraded to 1.16 I suddenly get a warning when I try to start my world:

[image]

People say this is because I've enabled snapshots, but I done that since forever and never had a warning like this before 1.16. And now I'm getting a little concerned that my world might be corrupted or something.

Is the warning really caused by enabling snapshots? Is there any way to get rid of it? Could this be a bug? Could my world be corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is indeed caused by enabling snapshots. Snapshots are intermediate releases that aren't tested properly. A snapshot may contain game breaking bugs like accidentally regenerating chunks in your worlds. It might be highly unstable, where certain new mobs may crash your game. Like, hard crash to desktop because an error occured that Java is unable to deal with. A snapshot might have basic things like jumping or mining broken. And there is no guarantee that things you've done in older versions still work in the snapshot version.

Snapshots are meant for enterprising players who want to play with the newest of the new content and aren't bothered if a bug ends up corrupting their world or destroying hours of their work. They just clarified that in 1.16 so people who may have accidentally enabled them are aware that they're using experimental settings that may end up ruining their world.

Comment: I see. In that case I really wish they added some way to undo the experimental settings. Like if you load your previously snapshot-enabled world in a non-snapshot release - you could scan for compatibility issues or something like that. Then, if the world was found to be "clean" and you disabled snapshots from there on - the warning would disappear. Like when they added that "optimize world" tool a while back. Something similar for this would be great.

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer. The warning for snapshots is different.

Answer (score 0):

The world you're trying to open is using [Customised world generation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Custom) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Custom&oldid=1693624)). These are still in an early development stage (and for some reason already included in full releases), so your world might not work correctly if you use them, especially if you load it after having created it in a different snapshot/release.